# Android universal music player add album cover in the MediaItemViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

Not sure how many people here are familiar with the [Android Universal Music Player](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) but I am having issue with displaying an album in the [MediaItemViewHolder.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/b729def3679cac2d66136e8fdc9237d01bfb485c/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/ui/MediaItemViewHolder.java#L75) file.

So here is a basic structure after my modifications:

```
// image view for the album cover
holder.mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.play_eq);

// get the album art url
String artUrl = description.getIconUri().toString();
Bitmap art;
AlbumArtCache cache = AlbumArtCache.getInstance();
art = cache.getIconImage(artUrl);
....
if (cachedState == null || cachedState != state) {
    switch (state) {
    case STATE_PLAYABLE:
         // display the album cover
         holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(art);
         break;
....
```

This correctly displays the album cover. However, **it is initially blank**. Once the user clicks on an item, the image is displayed.

**Screenshot #1** : Once the app is loaded and user did not click on any item:

[image]

**Screenshot #2** : Once the user click on the item to play the song

[image]

I am not really sure what is causing the album to be initially blank. Looking at the [AlbumArtCache.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/b729def3679cac2d66136e8fdc9237d01bfb485c/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/AlbumArtCache.java#L75) I can't see any restrictions about OnClickListener that can cause this.

Any suggestions how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cache.getIconImage(url)` does not actually fetch the url and store it in the cache. It returns the current value or null. Instead you have to call `AlbumArtCache#fetch(String url, FetchListener listener)`

A good prototype of this is in `FullScreenPlayerActivity#fetchImageAsync(MediaDescription description)`

Here is what you could do in a method when the item is playable.

```
AlbumArtCache cache = AlbumArtCache.getInstance();
Bitmap art = cache.getIconImage(url);
if (art == null) {
  cache.fetch(url, new AlbumArtCache.FetchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFetched(String artUrl, Bitmap bitmap, Bitmap icon) {
                if (artUrl.equals(url)) {
                    holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(icon);
                }
            }
        });
} else {
    holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: @nagesh-susaria
I attempted to give this a try on my local copy but I am getting something like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BycOIcYbBvF_WVpCcUJCcEtCSG8/view?usp=sharing

I have tried different ways of implementing this but arrive at the same result - am I hitting a bug (I have Android 5.1.1) or is this a PEBCAK issue, lol.

Comment: Is your onFetched(..) getting called? Can you add a debug statement to see if it reaches there. I can't tell what could be the problem w/o looking at the code.

Comment: Yeah - I'll be debugging this today - thanks for the tip.

Comment: @avluis have you resolved your issue? if not, take a look at the xml file and remove the tint for the image.

Comment: @NageshSusarla please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607919/not-getting-thumb-with-genres-universal-music-player